# Is there any way to pass connection string (connection manager) for SSIS package while adding job in command parameter

Tags: sql-server, ssis, arguments, connection-string, jobs

How to pass connection manager(connection string)while creating a Job using T-SQL statement, having SSIS package as steps or process?

Example:

```
DECLARE @SSIScommand as NVARCHAR(max)

SET @SSIScommand = '/ISSERVER "\"'+@package+'\"" /SERVER 
"\"'+@servername+'\""' 
+ '/Par "\"$Project::MyParam\"";' + @params +' '
+ '/CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = 'Job Name',
    @step_name = N'process step',
    @subsystem = N'SSIS',
    @command = @SSIScommand
```

Now, i want to pass connection string in above @SSIScommand 
I have modified as below but it is not working

```
SET @SSIScommand = '/ISSERVER "\"'+@package+'\"" /SERVER 
"\"'+@servername+'\""' 
+ '/Con "NameofConnectionstring";"\"'+ @ConnectionString +'\""'
+ '/Par "\"$Project::MyParam\"";' + @params +' '
+ '/CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E'
```

I don't know where am making mistake, can anyone help me to come out of this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `/conn` instead of `/con`. Example:

```
dtexec /F MyPackage.dtsx /CONN "MyConnection"\;"\"MyConnectionString\""
```

In your case, i think you should use the following syntax:

```
SET @SSIScommand = '/ISSERVER "\"'+@package+'\"" /SERVER 
"\"'+@servername+'\""' 
+ '/conn "NameofConnectionstring";"\"'+ @ConnectionString +'\""'
+ '/Par "\"$Project::MyParam\"";' + @params +' '
+ '/CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E'
```

**Reference**

- [Using dtexec from Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017#bash)